# Trying to add an SFTP user without changing ownership to them

Tags: permissions, users, sftp

I'm running CentOS 6.9.

I'd like to add SFTP users that can access certain directories. For one of them, I'd like them to be able to access everything (with SFTP permissions only and no shell access).

So far I added them:

```
adduser username
passwd username
```

... entered password.

Then I edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match User username
ForceCommand internal-sftp
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChrootDirectory /
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

Now, all the other instructions I see are to use `chown` for this user. BUT, I don't want to change ownership of the entire directory to this user. I just want this user to be able to access the entire directory without affecting the ownership permissions of any other users.

How can I do this?

Comment: Research ACL; e.g., `setfacl`.

Comment: @G-Man Looked into that. The documentation isn't really clear. Could you explain how to use that for my purposes?

Comment: @Christopher so would setfacl -Rdm u:username:rwx / provide full permissions for that user? Thanks

Comment: @Christopher Thank you!. You're right combining them didn't work but the 2 separate commands did

Comment: @Christopher This just cause a error 500 on all of my sites!!

Comment: @Christopher holy shit. You just saved my job with the setfacl -Rb / command. So many sites were down. I had done it on /var/www

Comment: @Christopher Yup the server log indicated "Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server". Again, you saved my ass with your fast reply with setfacl -Rb /.. Thanks!

Comment: @Christopher I think I must have first ran the comment at / by accident, which would have caused the issue. Thanks again for all your help.